# How to add a tagged equation in a list of equations?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsmath, tags

Similar to `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`, I would like to create a `\listofequations` command. This works well for equations that follow the continuity of the numbering, but it does not work with a tagged equation.

I don't know how to build a command that takes `\theequation` in the case of a numbered equation or the tag for a tagged equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox, hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listeq}[1]{\global\def\eqtitle{#1}}

\def\eqtitle{}%

\apptocmd{\maketag@@@}{%
        \addcontentsline{loe}{equation}{%
            \protect\numberline{\theequation}%
            \eqtitle%
        }%
        \global\def\eqtitle{}%
    }
    {}
    {\FAIL}

\newcommand\listequationname{List of equations}
\newcommand\listofequations{%
    \section*{\listequationname}%
    \@starttoc{loe}%
}
\newcommand*\l@equation{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofequations
\begin{equation}\listeq{First equation}
    i^2=-1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\listeq{Not working}
    i^2=-1 \tag{*}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\listeq{Not working too}
    i^2=-1 \tag*{*}
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
        i^2=-1
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\listeq{A subequation}
        i^2=-1
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\begin{align}
    i^2=-1\listeq{Eq 1}\\
    i^2=-1\listeq{Eq 2}\\
    i^2=-1\tag{§}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Writing something like this does not work:

```
\apptocmd{\maketag@@@}{%
        \addcontentsline{loe}{equation}{%
            \protect\numberline{#1}%
            \eqtitle%
        }%
        \def\eqtitle{}%
    }
    {}
    {\FAIL}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries, I think I found a solution. This one is not very elegant, but it works for the few cases I tested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox, hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listeq}[1]{\gdef\eqtitle{#1}}

\def\eqtitle{}%
\def\thecurrenttag{\theequation}%

\apptocmd{\maketag@@@}{%
            \addcontentsline{loe}{equation}{%
                \protect\numberline{\thecurrenttag}%
                \eqtitle%
            }%
        \gdef\eqtitle{}%
        \gdef\thecurrenttag{\theequation}%
    }
    {}
    {\FAIL}

\apptocmd{\make@df@tag@@}{%
        \gdef\thecurrenttag{#1}%
    }
    {}
    {\FAIL}
    
\apptocmd{\make@df@tag@@@}{%
        \gdef\thecurrenttag{#1}%
    }
    {}
    {\FAIL}

\newcommand\listequationname{List of equations}
\newcommand\listofequations{%
    \section*{\listequationname}%
    \@starttoc{loe}%
}
\newcommand*\l@equation{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofequations
\begin{equation}\listeq{First equation}
    i^2=-1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    i^2=-1 \tag{*}\listeq{Working}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\listeq{Working too}
    i^2=-1 \tag*{\$}
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
        i^2=-1
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\listeq{A subequation}
        i^2=-1
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\begin{align}
    i^2=-1\listeq{An align}\\
    i^2=-1\\
    i^2=-1\tag{§}\\
    i^2=-1
\end{align}
\begin{multline}\tag{£}\listeq{A multiline --- Working}\label{multline}
a+b+c+d+e+f\\
+g+h+i+j+k+l\\
+m+n+o+p+q+r
\end{multline}
\begin{gather}\tag{µ}\listeq{A gather}
a_1=b_1+c_1\\
a_2=b_2+c_2-d_2+e_2
\end{gather}
\begin{flalign}
a_{11} + b_{11}& = c_{11}&
a_{12}& =b_{12}\\\tag{\#}\listeq{A flalign}
b_{21}& = c_{21}&
a_{22}& =b_{22}+c_{22}
\end{flalign}
\begin{alignat}{2}
x& = y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dots
&\quad& \text{bla bla bla}\\\tag{\&}\listeq{An alignat}
& = y’\circ y^* && \text{bla bla bla}\\
& = y(0) y’ && \text {bla bla bla}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

However, there is still a problem with the `multline` environment :

[image]

After looking at the definition of `multline@`, I noticed that the problem was with the `mmeasure@` command. Commenting out one line seems to solve the problem but I don't know if it is very safe to do that and if it will not create problems in some circumstances.

```
\def\mmeasure@#1{%
    \begingroup
    \measuring@true
    \def\label##1{%
        \begingroup\measuring@false\label@in@display{##1}\endgroup%
    }%
    \def\math@cr@@@{\cr}%
    \let\shoveleft\@iden \let\shoveright\@iden
    \savecounters@
    \global\row@\z@
    \setbox\@ne\vbox{%
        \global\let\df@tag\@empty
        \halign{%
            \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{}##$}%
            \iftagsleft@
                \ifnum\row@=\@ne
                    \global\totwidth@\wdz@
                    \global\lineht@\ht\z@
                \fi
            \else
                \global\totwidth@\wdz@
                \global\lineht@\dp\z@
            \fi
            \crcr
            #1%
            \crcr
        }%
    }%
    \ifx
        \df@tag\@empty
    \else
        \global\tag@true
    \fi
    \if@eqnsw
        \global\tag@true
    \fi
    \iftag@
        \setboxz@h{%
            \if@eqnsw
                \stepcounter{equation}%
                \tagform@\theequation
            \else
                % \df@tag % !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            \fi
        }%
        \global\tagwidth@\wdz@
        \dimen@\totwidth@
        \advance\dimen@\tagwidth@
        \advance\dimen@\multlinetaggap
        \iftagsleft@\else
            \if@fleqn
                \advance\dimen@\@mathmargin
            \fi
        \fi
        \ifdim\dimen@>\displaywidth
            \global\shifttag@true
        \else
            \global\shifttag@false
        \fi
    \fi
    \restorecounters@
    \endgroup
}
```

[image]